# How to read and write to an external json file?

Tags: javascript, json

Anyone know how to read and write to an external JSON file using native javascript?

We are creating some sort of web application that allows me to create layouts using 2d drag and drop functionalities. Now, the major concern that I have is that I need to insert HTML elements references on my external JSON file.
I am successful in creating my layouts and all, but if I refresh my page, naturally my designs will disappear because i am using no backend on my web application. We were told that we have to use an external JSON file to accomplish this.

I do know we have to save all the html elements on the JSON file, and creating references of those is barely a problem. But the reading and writing from and to the external JSON file is what bothers me. If there is a way using native JS that would be great, we weren't told to use other languages or superscripts.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to write to an external file in JavaScript for security reasons, though of course you can parse and decode JSON objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External files cannot be written to via JavaScript. Though, HTML5 brings along `localStorage`, storage that can hold `string`s and `integer`s. We know that JSON can be serialized from a JavaScript object, and that a JavaScript object can be serialized from a JSON string.

Therefore, you could save your data to and from `localStorage`, serializing as you go:

```
var obj = {"audi": "r8", "color": "black"};

localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And to retrieve the object later

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStorage'));
```

Comment: Thats not really an external *file* though really, is it?

Comment: It's somewhat of an alternative if he is required to do without the backend or only use JavaScript, as I believe he noted.

Comment: You could use fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback); ?

Comment: Literally saw this answer on a similar question. Haven't tried it yet though. 

I'll try .writeFile() soon. Is fs supposed to be a variable

Comment: ES5 doesn't have that functionality in a standard environment (corlib).

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for this purpose. Here is a sample code to read a local file and display the content in UI.

```html
<html>
    <body>

        <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
        <div id="ReadResult"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function readSingleFile(evt) {
                //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
                var f = evt.target.files[0];

                if (f) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                        document.getElementById("ReadResult").innerHTML = contents;
                    }
                    r.readAsText(f);
                } else {
                    alert("Failed to load file");
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Look [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=8xJLdXcF3hW) for more details.

Comment: how about writing?

Comment: I don't recall OP mentioning that he wanted to serialize user JSON. And doesn't the File Reader API only **read** files, not edit them?